# Best way to join objects for texturing and game engines?

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

I’m modelling a game asset and I’m wondering what’s the best approach for joining a mesh which consists of many different parts. I don’t want to overlap my objects because they all have different vertex count and they are different shapes.

What I mean is if I have an object and it consists of many parts and I want to model and texture them separately, is it ok to join them later using a simple command such as ctrl+J. Or would that not be good when they are exported to a game engine in terms or re-applying textures and things like that.

Waiting for help!

Comment: In Blender 2.8 you don't have to merge seperate objects to one to make a mutual uv layout, because if you select all of them and then go to edit mode, you can edit all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The correct workflow is to wait as long as you can before joining anything. Having separate objects is useful for UV mapping, baking normal, and texturing in general. For this reason you should aim at joining your object only when it's time to model a low poly version of it, and in the case where you don't have a low poly version you should only join them just before exporting your mesh to your game engine.

Comment: I kind of understand. My model is already low poly, I didn’t do a high poly version of it. My plan is to texture paint all objects separately, and once that’s done, join them together. But what would happen to their separate texture maps once it’s all joined? Will it become one big texture map/material? Because I’m concerned about how the game engine would define and find the texture map for different objects if it’s all joined into one big mesh?